# Debian 9 graphics driver update (ATI)

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, graphics-card

I'm a new Debian 9 user trying to update my graphics card driver. If I look at the Debian wiki page for ATIProprietary, I don't see Debian 9 and am not sure if I can use one of the older drivers. I'm not sure if my card is supported. I checked the open source drivers but it seems like those are only for newer cards. Below are my specs.

- AMD Turion II 2.4 ghz dual core
- HD Mobillity Radeon 4200 gpu
- Debian 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [ATI HowTo on the debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Installation):

> ### Installation
>
> The following procedure will install the open source display driver
>   packages, DRI modules (for 3D acceleration) and driver
>   firmware/microcode:
>
> Add "contrib" and "non-free" components to /etc/apt/sources.list, for
>   example:
>
> ```
>  # Debian 8 "Jessie"
>  deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
> ```
>
> Update the list of available packages:
>
> ```
> # apt-get update
> ```
>
> Install the firmware-linux-nonfree, libgl1-mesa-dri and
>   xserver-xorg-video-ati packages:
>
> ```
> # apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-ati
> ```
>
> Restart your system to load GPU device firmware.

But you don't need to update your driver in case everything works well so far.

Comment: I'd appreciate you answering my questions. Not just posting a link to something I've already seen for which I've had questions about.

Comment: @DavidChilds your questions should be answered by the wiki, the only difference being the current name of stable (stretch). If you did this already, that (and what happened & why it doesn't work) should  be in your question

Comment: I just didn't want to brick my system. So I asked. I'll try and if I don't come back, it's 'cause it worked. Thanks.